# Auto delete rows with Kafka's JdbcSinkConnector?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have an in-memory database and I'm using Kafka + JdbcSinkConnector to sync a downstream Postgres database with the in-memory database. The in-memory database is for efficient computations and Postgres is for querying. In development, I frequently destroy and recreate the in-memory database. Each time, I also recreate the Kafka sink connectors.

If new rows were added or existing rows were changed in the in-memory database, I think JdbcSinkConnector is able to sync Postgres with the new data. However, if rows were deleted, JdbcSinkConnector doesn't delete the rows in Postgres.

Is it possible for JdbcSinkConnector to check which of the rows in the downstream database are no longer in the upstream database, then delete them? If not, I'd have to destroy the downstream database every time I update the upstream database.

Config:

```
{
  'connector.class': 'io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector',
  'dialect.name': 'PostgreSqlDatabaseDialect',
  'key.converter': 'io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter',
  'key.converter.schema.registry.url': `http://schema-registry:${process.env.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PORT}`,
  'value.converter': 'io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter',
  'value.converter.schema.registry.url': `http://schema-registry:${process.env.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PORT}`,
  'insert.mode': 'upsert',
  'delete.enabled': 'true',
  'auto.create': 'true',
  'auto.evolve': 'false',
  'errors.retry.timeout': -1,
  'connection.url': `jdbc:postgresql://${process.env.INTERNAL_DOCKER_HOST}:${process.env.PG_PORT}/${process.env.PG_DB}`,
  'connection.user': process.env.PG_USER,
  'connection.password': process.env.PG_PASS,
  'pk.mode': 'record_key',
}
```

Comment: Yes, the sink supports deletes (check the docs). No it's not automatic... What are you using to source the data from the "in memory database"?

Comment: The only related config I see is `delete.enabled`, afaik it works only when a row is deleted while the connector is running

Comment: Rows get deleted when it [consumes a non-null key and null value](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/sink-connector/index.html#jdbc-sink-delete-mode). Again, what is sourcing your in memory database or producing events for the sink to consume?

Comment: The in-memory database is Materialize, it has a Kafka sink: https://materialize.com/docs/sql/create-sink/. It shouldn't be creating tombstone records, since I'm recreating the database instead of just deleting rows

Comment: Then, you've answered your own question. If it won't create tombstone records, then the jdbc sink won't delete anything

Answer (score 1):

> possible for JdbcSinkConnector to check which of the rows in the downstream database are no longer in the upstream database

It's fully decoupled from any knowledge of the upstream system, so no.

> I'd have to destroy the downstream database every time I update the upstream database.

Truncate, not destroy/drop. Unless your upstream database schema is changed. You'd need some external notification event to trigger that; could be a REST API, not necessarily a Kafka event

---

Unclear why you need to use Materialize when Kafka Streams KTables would also allow for quick storage and backing by topics, and they support writing tombstone events that are needed for the JDBC sink to delete data.